# mercurial repo with bookmarks converted to mercurial -- no bookmarks?

Tags: mercurial, split, bookmarks

I have a mercurial repository, which I need to be splitted into parts. I've [`convert`'ed it to mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_to_Mercurial), everything is great, but the new repository has no bookmarks from old one.

How can this be fixed, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg` stores your bookmarks in two files in the `.hg` folder, namely `bookmarks` and  `bookmarks.current`.

Since the bookmarks are referenced with the changeset id hash (which stays the same between repos) simply copying the two files to the `.hg` folder in the newly `convert`-ed repo should set them up properly.

Comment: However, it seems that it was my fault actually .) `hg convert` did it's job right, but I did not `push -B` my bookmarks. Sorry .) And THANK YOU.